# Can't input text into form or click search button

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Any idea why this code stopped working? (Wordpress)

[My site](http://www.codytritter.com/) - The main search bar 'city' 'neighborhood' 'min price' etc isn't responding, I can't input text and have no clue what I've done to bung it up.

[The code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKbxOj) seems to be clean though when I input it in the codepen, something on my site is mucking this up!

```
    <form id="sp_search_w" action="http://www.codytritter.com/listing/" method="get">
        <input name="sp" type="hidden" value="s" /> 
        <label for="sp_city">City</label> 
        <input id="sp_city" class="btn-block" name="sp_city" type="text" placeholder="City" /> 
        <label for="sp_subdivision">Sub Division</label> 
        <input id="sp_subdivision" class="btn-block" name="sp_subdivision" type="text" placeholder="Neighborhood" /> 
        <label for="sp_minprice">Min. Price</label> 
        <input name="sp_minprice" type="text" placeholder="Min Price" /> 

        <!--
        <select name="sp_minprice" id="sp_minprice" class="btn-block">
           <option value="0">No Min</option>
           <option value="25000">25,000</option>
           <option value="50000">50,000</option>
           <option value="75000">75,000</option>
       </select>
       --> 

       <label for="sp_maxprice">Max. Price</label> 
       <input name="sp_maxprice" type="text" placeholder="Max Price" /> 

       <!-- 
       <select name="sp_maxprice" id="sp_maxprice" class="btn-block">
           <option value="50000000">No Max</option>
           <option value="25000">25,000</option>
           <option value="50000">50,000</option>
           <option value="75000">75,000</option>
       </select> 
       --> 

       <label for="sp_bedrooms">Bedrooms</label> 
       <input class="short" name="sp_bedrooms" type="text" placeholder="Beds" /> 
       <!--
       <select name="sp_bedrooms" id="sp_bedrooms" class="input-small btn-block">
           <option value="">All</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4+</option>
       </select> 
       -->

       <label for="sp_bathrooms">Bathroom</label> 
       <input class="short" name="sp_bathrooms" type="text" placeholder="Baths" />

       <!--
       <select name="sp_bathrooms" id="sp_bathrooms" class="input-small btn-block">
           <option value="">All</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4+</option>
       </select>
       -->
       <div class="controls">
            <input id="sp_search_submit" class="btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
       </div>
   </form>
```

CSS

```
form { 
   max-width: 100%; 
   margin: auto; 
   text-align: center; 
} 

 input { 
   text-align: center; 
   padding: 1rem 1rem; 
   border-radius: .5rem; 
   border: 2px solid #ddd; 
   font-size: 1.3em; 
   max-width: 8em; 
 } 

 .controls { padding: 1em 0 0; }

 #sp_search_submit { 
   background: #809eb6; 
   border: 0; 
   color: #fff; 
   text-transform: uppercase; 
   letter-spacing: .2rem; 
 } 

 input:focus { outline: 0; } 
 .short { max-width: 4em; } 
 label { display: none; }
```

Comment: form {
max-width: 100%;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

input {
text-align: center;
padding: 1rem 1rem;
border-radius: .5rem;
border: 2px solid #ddd;
font-size: 1.3em;
max-width: 8em;
}

.controls {
padding: 1em 0 0;
}

#sp_search_submit {
background: #809eb6;
border: 0;
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .2rem;
}

input:focus {
outline: 0;
}

.short {
max-width: 4em;
}

label {
display: none;
}
}

Comment: don't include your code in comments

Comment: I cleaned it up for him

Comment: When having strange problems, always start by validating your source code https://validator.w3.org/. For example, missing closing tags has been for me the most usual cause of strange behavior of html pages.

Answer (score 2):

It's a CSS problem. There is a `z-index` of -1 on a parent element.

See this style

```
.post-489 .et_pb_section:nth-child(1) {
    z-index: -1!important;
}
```

It's references in the head of your page

```
<!-- Start CSSHero.org Dynamic CSS & Fonts Loading -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.codytritter.com?wpcss_action=show_css" data-apply-prefixfree />
<!-- End CSSHero.org Dynamic CSS & Fonts Loading -->
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm having a hard time with CSS hero finding where this is though. It seems all of my z-index are set to 9999 or auto and I can't find the .css file to actually modify!

Comment: I figured it out, if I could kiss you I would. Thank you so much Tristan, you just made my day.